# Does imported functions from the same source, have access to their source global variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, package, global-variables

OK i searched every site i knew, using every keyword i knew, but i found nothing close the subject i searched about, maybe the whole question is wrong, but anyway...

let's say we have a module named `Index.js`, which contains a `STORAGE` and two functions responsible for reading/writing to `STORAGE`.

```js
var STORAGE = []

function writeStorage(data) {
  STORAGE.push(data)
}

function readStorage(data) {
  //find data in STORAGE... and return result as RES
  return RES
}
```

Now, inside a file named `write.js`, we import `writeStorage()`.

While in another file named `read.js`, we import `readStorage()`.

And this is where the question rises,

**Does imported functions from the same source, have access to their source global variables ?**

i.e, can we modify `STORAGE` in `index.js`, using `writeStorage()` which we imported in `write.js` ?

and read `STORAGE` changes from `read.js` using `readStorage()` ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to provide clearer answer about that. There are two scopes for functions: lexical, and dynamic. **Dynamic** means, a function will search variables in the area, where it was **called**:

```
let someVar = 'global';

function dynamicScope () {
    someVar = 'dynamic';
    console.log(somevar);
}

dynamicalScope(); // will display 'global'
```

**Lexical** means, the function will search variables where it was **written/declared**:

```
let someVar = 'global';

function lexicalScope () {
    someVar = 'lexical';
    console.log(somevar);
} 

lexicalScope(); // will display 'lexical'
```

But in JavaScript, **there is no way to use dynamic scope**, so all function will search variables **where it has been declared/written**.

**DO NOT PAY ATTENTION ON DETAILS, IT'S JUST A PSEUDO-CODE.**

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.

This post might also help in understanding:
[Same javascript module imported in different files, sharing the same lexical scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69922721/same-javascript-module-imported-in-different-files-sharing-the-same-lexical-sco)

A further example to demonstrate @Azamat 's answer

```js
//file_to_import.js
let fruit = 'banana';
let fruits = []

export function describeFruit(){
    console.log(`The ${fruit} is yellow`)
}

export function listFruits () {
    console.log(`Fruits: ${fruits.join(', ')}`)
}

export function addFruits (fruitToAdd) {
    fruits.push(fruitToAdd)
}


setTimeout(listFruits, 1000)
setTimeout(listFruits, 5000)



//index.js
import { addFruits, describeFruit} from "./file_to_import.js"; //import brings in functions and initializes (runs) all code from the file_to_import.js

//Declare a variable named 'fruit' .  There now exists two fruit variables - one in the scope of this file (index.js) which is the string 'apple' and the other in the scope of the imported file (file_to_import) which is the string 'banana'.
let fruit = 'apple'

//Demonstrate the imported function has access to the variables in the scope from which it was declared
describeFruit() // logs 'the banana is yellow' demonstrating the access to the variable 'fruit' in file_to_import.js NOT to the variable fruit as declared here


// Code from 1st setTimeout (1000ms delay) from file_to_import executes, showing we have no fruits in our 'fruits' array as declared in file_to_import
// Code from this setTimeout (3000ms delay) executes, adding the variable fruit, as it exists in the scope of this file, to the array 'fruits' as it is exists in the file_to_import scope
setTimeout(()=>addFruits(fruit), 3000); 
//Code from 2nd setTimeout (5000ms delay) from file_to_import executes showing we now have an apple in our array
```